# Soft kill vs hard kill in unix

Tags: linux, unix

Can anyone knows internals/ difference between executing these two commands in unix? I have been told soft kill will wait for all threads to terminate started by this process. My process is a tomcat server.

Kill -9 pid
Kill pid

Answer (score 1):

Invoking `kill` command sends a `signal` to the process or process group.

1. When we invoke `kill -9 PID`. The signal sent to process / process group is to `exit` with no blocking.
2. When no signal is passed to `kill` viz. `kill PID`, the default signal is passed to `kill`.

The  default  signal  for  kill is `TERM`, and in such cases the command is interpreted as `kill -15 PID`.

More detailed information on `kill` is surely available in [Linux `man` pages](http://linuxcommand.sourceforge.net/lc3_man_pages/kill1.html).

Another good description available in this [document](https://linux.die.net/man/1/kill) which says;

> The command kill sends the specified signal to the specified process
>   or process group. If no signal is specified, the TERM signal is sent.
>   The TERM signal will kill processes which do not catch this signal.
>   For other processes, it may be necessary to use the KILL (9) signal,
>   since this signal cannot be caught.

Which means that though usual `kill PID` can do your job for all those processes where `TERM` signal is uncaught. Using `-9` becomes imperative where `TERM` signal is tolerated.